# Rendering PartialView with complex object using jquery in .Net Core - not returning to ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a very complex structure for my .Net 5 core mvc application. I am trying to use jquery to call controller method. I could send the json model to the controller. The controller action method is getting the json object and process. But the ajax call is not hitting the success part and thus cannot render the partial view.

The functionality is to process the data for the selected checkboxes in the grid and display results accordingly. The jquery for check / uncheck is working fine.

When the btnRevokeSelected is clicked, it calls the /CDFAU/Revoke action but never comes to the *success part* of the ajax call.

**Controller Method**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Revoke([FromBody] CDFAUViewModel cdf)
    {
        ViewData["UserName"] = "XYZ";
        CDFAUViewModel viewModel = new CDFAUViewModel();
        viewModel.Parameters = cdf.Parameters;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel = await _cdfauService.RevokeSelectedUserEntityAccess(viewModel);
        }
        return PartialView("Home", viewModel);
    }
```

**Layout div to render in**

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid" style="border:2px solid black;">        
        @RenderBody()
</div>
```

**Home View section with the button**

```
<div class="row" style="width:100%; padding-top:0.5%; padding-left:2%;">
    @*border:1px solid blue;*@
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
        @*border: 2px solid red;*@
        <div class="col-lg-8" style="width:100%;">
            @*border:1px solid green;*@
            <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
                @*border: 2px solid red;*@
                @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, null, FormMethod.Post, false, new { id = "formUserAccessRevoke", style = "width:100%; margin-bottom: 0.5%;" }))
                {
                    <button type="submit" id="btnRevokeSelected" title="Revoke Selected" class="btn btn-dark btn-info">
                        @*asp-controller="CDFAU" asp-action="Revoke"*@
                        <img src="~/Images/revoke.png" />
                        <span class="bttn-text">Revoke</span>
                    </button>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
                @*border: 2px solid red;*@
                <div id="partialViewContainer" class="col" style=" width:100%;">
                    @*border:1px solid blue;*@
                    @{ 
                        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_UserAccessDetails", Model.UserAccess);
                    }                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4" style="width:100%; ">
            @*border:1px solid green;*@
            <p>messages</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#btnRevokeSelected').click(function () {
    
    var mainModel = {};
    var parameters = {};

    CreateParametersModelObject('#formUserAccessActions', parameters);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(mainModel));
    mainModel.Parameters = parameters;

    if ($('#formUserAccessDetails1').length) {
        var _userAccess1 = {};
        CreateUserAccessModelObject("#formUserAccessDetails1", _userAccess1);
        mainModel.UserAccess1 = _userAccess1;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(_userAccess1));
    } else {
        mainModel.UserAccess1 = {};
    }


    if ($('#formUserAccessDetails2').length) {
        var _userAccess2 = {};
        CreateUserAccessModelObject("#formUserAccessDetails2", _userAccess2);
        mainModel.UserAccess2 = _userAccess2;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(_userAccess2));
    } else {
        mainModel.UserAccess2 = {};
    }


    if ($('#formUserAccessDetails3').length) {
        var _userAccess3 = {};
        CreateUserAccessModelObject("#formUserAccessDetails3", _userAccess3);
        mainModel.UserAccess3 = _userAccess3;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(_userAccess3));
    } else {
        mainModel.UserAccess3 = {};
    }


    if ($('#formUserAccessDetails4').length) {
        var _userAccess4 = {};
        CreateUserAccessModelObject("#formUserAccessDetails4", _userAccess4);
        mainModel.UserAccess4 = _userAccess4;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(_userAccess4));
    } else {
        mainModel.UserAccess4 = {};
    }


    if ($('#formUserAccessDetails5').length) {
        var _userAccess5 = {};
        CreateUserAccessModelObject("#formUserAccessDetails5", _userAccess5);
        mainModel.UserAccess5 = _userAccess5;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(_userAccess5));
    } else {
        mainModel.UserAccess5 = {};
    }

    //alert(JSON.stringify(mainModel));
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(mainModel));
    //alert(model);'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'*@
       $.ajax({
            url: "/CDFAU/Revoke",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(mainModel),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Have you put the breakpoint in your controller and tried to debug it? On which line does code execution get stuck? Are you receiving any error or warning messages? if yes, kindly share it here. It may help to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: No error, controller method executing fine, only it is not hitting the success of ajax call, tried tracking in browser network tracker, no script error

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue. The ajax call needs to changed this way. The rendering of the partial view needs to be done in done rather than success.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(mainModel),
        url: "/CDFAU/Revoke",
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                //alert(response.responseText);
            } else {
                // DoSomethingElse()
                //alert(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            //alert("error!");  // 
        }
    }).done(function (response) {
        //debugger;            
        $('#partialViewContainer').html('');
        $('#partialViewContainer').html(response);
    });
```

The success / error / failure can be handled according to the need.